# Are Energy-Based Models actually used in real data science jobs?

Tags: machine-learning

I have seen several algorithms used in data science job, but I haven’t heard so much about Energy-based models. Do they actually find application in companies and in real  jobs in data science besides the academic research ?

Comment: Can you extend your question with some examples?

Comment: I know that some people use PCA as a technique to reduce dimensionality and that it used in real life, such as  in jobs  in companies. Also, I know  that transformer architecture is used a  lot. My questions is: do energy-based  model actually find application in industry, or it is just  something they teach but that  no one will actually need?

Comment: When i say Energy-based models i meas Boltzmann Machines or restricted Boltzmann Machines, or Autoencoders.

Comment: I see, you mean https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy-based_generative_neural_network

Comment: It seems like one of the strengths is that the ebms are generative. Honestly, as of 2024 most models which I used  are non-generative

Answer (score 3):

I have never used Boltzmann Machines or similar models in my past 6 years of data science experience. I have worked in NLP, Computer Vision, Search, Transaction Frauds etc.

But I have used Autoencoders multiple times to generate embedding, detecting outliers in Fraud Transactions.

I dont think energy based models is popular currently among practicing data scientists.

Comment: +1 I think this is due to the fact that no popular library serves them out of the box. Typically your main constraint is time to build a model - my experience